# outlined border change to single line when click -flutter error

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a login page. when I click on email/username field it becomes one line rather than displaying outlined border. how to overcome this issue.

[image]   [image]

```
TextFormField(
            controller: emailEditingController,
            enabled: true,
            decoration:  InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue,),
              ),
              //isDense: true,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 30, 10, 0),

                hintText: "Email/ Username",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: textblue, fontFamily: "Dubai", fontSize: 14),
            ),
            validator: (String? UserName) {
              if (UserName != null && UserName.isEmpty) {
                return "Email can't be empty";
              }
              return null;
            },
            onChanged: (String? text) {
              email = text!;
              // print(email);
            },
            onSaved: (value) {
              loginUserData['email'] = value!;
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When focused, it uses the `focusedBorder`. You can specify `focusedBorder` with the same one as the one you used for `enabledBorder`.

```dart
decoration:  InputDecoration(
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
    borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
  ),
  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
    borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
  ),
  // ...
),
```

You might also have to specify `errorBorder`, `focusedErrorBorder` and `disabledBorder`

- `enabledBorder` is used when the field is enabled.
- `focusedBorder` is used when the field is focused.
- `errorBorder` is used when the field has an error (from your form validatin)
- `focusedErrorBorder` is used when the field has an error and is focused
- `disabledBorder` is used when the field is disabled

Comment: it seems like working... but when I give empty values  and click login button, again it display 'email can't be empty' as a single line

Comment: edited the question with error image. please check

Comment: You can then specify `errorBorder` and `focusErrorBorder`,

I'll update my answer

Comment: now its highlight the border with red color. but when I start typing on that error field ,it again becomes single line.

Comment: Have you specified all 4 borders `enabledBorder` `focusedBorder` `errorBorder` and `focusedErrorBorder` ?